# Started a new job and already feel like quitting, but I have a 6 month probation period

Tags: resignation, work-experience, quitting

So I've been working for this interior design company for a week and a half, under the impression that I would be sourcing clients in sales rather than being a interior designer-in-training. And now my boss has put me in charge of overseeing a project, which I have little to no knowledge of handling, like advising what workers need to do, ordering and scheduling when things need to be done.

The only way I can describe how I feel is being thrown into the middle of the ocean with bare knowledge of how to float in water. I'm not comfortable with how they've put me onto a project so quickly without assessing if I was ready or not and the idea of even staying for six months makes me want to cave my head in.

Is this normal to feel like this, in my situation? I kind of want to turn in my week's notice right at this moment but I've only been working for 9 days AND put in charge of overseeing a work site AND designing a client's home layout. Is there a way to write out a resignation letter without creating bad blood?  );

Answer (score 5):

From what I make out of it, You've been given responsibility to overlook other members of staff. This is a perfect opportunity for you in your career so I would definitely refrain from leaving (especially this early on).

However if you feel you lack experience/knowledge and are out of your comfort zone as of now, Book a 1-1 in with your manager and explain to them that you will be happy doing this in the future but at the moment it is not something you're comfortable doing.

You may be taking this too personal and overlooking the fact that you've got a great chance here to be an important part of the company especially so early on.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the starting comment; the company is a very small one, and I have no "team" to aid me on this project as the workers on site are from their own companies. Essentially if I were to be trained under them, in the haphazard way they have done so, I would be designer, sales agent, overseer, purchaser, etc. The only reason they handed this project to me (with the little unqualified experience that I have) is to lessen the boss's load

Comment: Then I recommend finding another job and just keep this one until you definitely have one sorted. Atleast you still get paid

Answer (score 2):

It's not normal to throw someone in that doesn't know how to do the task.

Having said that you expected a sales role yet applied for a job as an interior designer. You must expect that mismatch to be a problem. An interior designer who does not know how to organise an interior to be done is not an asset. Even a sales person with less than satisfactory knowledge of the industry is of dubious worth.

> Is there a way to write out a resignation letter without creating bad blood?

One of the purposes behind a probation period is judging whether a person is a good fit for a job. You should take advantage of this fact as soon as possible before things get messier than they already are. There is no need for bad blood.

Comment: I admit on my part that I was expecting to do more sales than be a part of the actual designing. But when I read through the contract it seemed more oriented to designing and I was too chicken to voice it out. I have given myself about two months from day one to see if I can settle in... But I just don't see myself working there for very long due to the hours and the massive amounts of duties to carry out.

Comment: we all make mistakes, best to resolve them before they blow out of proportion or affect your mental state.